# Proper IUPAC name of a substituted cyclohexenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Here's the molecule:

[image]

So far I've tried: 6-methylcyclohex-2-en-ol and 4-methylcyclohexen-3-ol but both are wrong. I'm rather confused as to where I should start: the alcohol or the double bond?

Answer (score 5):

I think you made a counting mistake. It is 6-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-ol

Comment: You are right. For those who have the software, many drawing packages have structure to IUPAC name modules (I use ChemDoodle). This is a quick way to verify name rules from structures.

Answer (score 1):

The functional group with highest precedence is the alcohol, so it will be the suffix and bears number 1. The main chain is cyclohexene, and you have two ways of numbering it:

- 5-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-ol
- 2-methylcyclohex-5-en-1-ol

However, IUPAC rules state that you must give double bonds at the lowest possible numbering, even before considering prefix groups (rule 6.1 to 6.4 of [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_organic_chemistry#Basic_principles)). So, it has to be **5-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-ol**.

Comment: Sorry but as pointed out above in the answer by "jens", this (otherwise great) answer has a typo.